# How many functions of $\Omega$ following the condition $f(1)=1$ for $\space \Omega = \{ \space f \mid f: A \rightarrow B\space \}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given $A=\{1,2,3..,n\}$,  $B=\{1,2,3,..,m\},$$\space \space $while $5<m,n$ $\space$ and $\space \Omega = \{ \space f \mid f: A \rightarrow B\space \}$

How many functions from $\space \Omega$ following the condition $f(1) = 1 ?$

I don't have any clue where to begin with, though I'm feeling kind of confused from the topics in the forum.

Comment: Clues: 1) it is a function, so for every element in A you have to associate one in B. 2) it is not necessarily injective, so to different elements in A you can assign the same element in B. 3) it is not necessarily subjective, so so elements in B may not be assigned to any in A.

Comment: @toliveira I tought about all those posibilities, but how can I calculate such thing.. even if the function is injective, nor subjective, there are many other functions that doesn't follow the condition f(1)=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  A function $f: A \to B$ is determined by how each element in the domain is assigned an image in the codomain.  By assumption, there is only one possible assignment for $f(1)$.  For each of the $n - 1$ other elements in the domain, there are $m$ possible ways to assign its image.  Apply the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_principle).

Comment: I can't really get the point. I know that there is only one possible assignment for each image, but the question is about the amount of functions that can manage this rule. for example, $f(x) = x^2$ and $f(x) = x^3$ both gives me the same image for the same domain in this case.

Comment: Consider a simple example.  Let $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$; let $B = \{1, 2\}$.  Then $\Omega$ is the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$ such that $f(1) = 1$.  There are four such functions:  \begin{align*} f_1(1) & = 1, & f_1(2) & = 1, & f_1(3) & = 1\\ f_2(1) & = 1, &  f_2(2) & = 1, & f_2(3) & = 2\\ f_3(1) & = 1, & f_3(2) & = 2, & f_3(3) & = 1\\ f_4(1) & = 1, & f_4(2) & = 2, & f_4(3) & = 2\end{align*}  The reason is that we have one choice for the image of $1$, two choices for the image of $2$, and two choices for the image of $3$, so we have $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 4$ possible functions.

Comment: So, we have one and only choice for the domain of $1$ ($A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{1\}$),multiply it with $m^{n-1}$ choices of the other domains? because we have n-1 domains left, and each domain be can assign to any possible $m$,

Comment: That is correct.   Because of the restriction that $f(1) = 1$, there are $m^{n - 1}$ functions from $A$ to $B$.  Without the restriction, the number of functions from $A$ to $B$ is $|B|^{|A|}$, where $|S|$ is the cardinality of set $S$.